# Почему не работает полиморфизм?

Tags: c++, полиморфизм

Есть иерархия классов

```
    class Hash {
    public:
      enum SIZE {
        PASSWORDSIZE = 16,
        HASHSIZE = 32
        };
    private:
      CryptoPP::SHA256 sha256;
    protected:
      std::string hash(std::string const&, SIZE const size = PASSWORDSIZE);
      };


      class FileInterface
      {
    public:
      class UnableToWrite : public std::exception {public: virtual const char* what() const noexcept override {return "unable to write data to file";}};
      
      FileInterface() = delete;
      FileInterface(const std::string & );
      virtual ~FileInterface();
      virtual bool empty() const;
      virtual bool update(std::string const&);
    
    protected:
      std::fstream *file;
      std::string data;

      };


  struct Password {

    virtual bool empty() = 0;
    virtual bool verification(std::string const&) = 0;
    virtual bool update(std::string const&) = 0;
    virtual ~Password() = 0;

    };


        class PasswordInterface : private Hash, public FileInterface, public Password
      {
    public:
      PasswordInterface();
      ~PasswordInterface();
      bool verification(std::string const&) override;
      bool empty() const override;
    private:
      std::string hashPassword(std::string const&);
      std::string passwordFromString(std::string const&);
      };
```

Далее в коде есть строка `Password *p = new PasswordInterface();` которая по идее должна нормально компилироваться ведь `PasswordInterface` это наследник класса `Password` но qt-creator ругается:

> runcommand.cpp:6:13: Cannot initialize a variable of type
> 'Password *' with an rvalue of type 'PasswordInterface
> *'

**Почему я не могу присвоить указателю на `Password` значение типа `PasswordInterface`* и как это исправить?**

Answer (score 1):

*Ошибка должна была быть другой : `error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'PasswordInterface'`*
Потому-что класс `class PasswordInterface` у вас абстрактный до тех-пор, пока у него не определены виртуальные функции базового класса со знаком `.. = 0 ;`.

Поменяйте в `struct Password` декларацию виртуальной функции с добавлением константности `const`. *Ваша константная функция **не** замещает не константную.*

```
virtual bool empty() const = 0;
```

Добавьте реализацию функции `virtual bool update(std::string const&) ;`.

```
virtual bool update(std::string const& s){
      return FileInterface :: update(s);
}
```

*Происходит наследование этой виртуальной функции от **двух** базовых классов. И решение, какую из них вызывать придётся сделать программисту явно.*

Comment: Реализация этой функции наследуется от FileInterface, и она срабатывает именно так как в FileInterface